# XmlHttpRequest from an iframe to site running Django fails

Tags: django, iframe, xmlhttprequest

I have an iframe from which I am trying to send a XMLHttpRequest. Here is the request code -

```
x=w.XMLHttpRequest?new XMLHttpRequest():(w.ActiveXObject?newActiveXObject('Microsoft.XMLHTTP'):0);
try{
if(!x)throw(0);
    x.open('GET','<url>',true);
    x.setRequestHeader('Content-Type','application/x-www-form-urlencoded');
    x.onreadystatechange=function(){
    if(x.readyState==4){
        if(x.status==200){
            try{
                alert('hi');
            }
            catch(e){}
        }
        else {  }
    }
    };
    x.send('a=blah');   
}catch(e){}
```

The url it sends request to is implemented in Django. When I try to send this request on chorme, I get following error - "XMLHttpRequest cannot load iframe-url. Origin http://example.com is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin."

I found [this](https://gist.github.com/426829) middleware for django but that didn't work. I couldn't found a way to allow "Access-Control-Allow-Origin" in django documentation either. Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This middleware do solves the problem - https://gist.github.com/426829
I added it in the wrong way.

Comment: I am also stuck with same. I can explain how it worked for you a bit more? I am also using the same Middleware and running a simple jQuery request on lookback and gettting same error as you. Thanks in advance.

Comment: In the settings.py add following line to the MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES - '<app_name>.crossdomainxhrmiddleware.XsSharing' and copy the middleware code in a file named - crossdomainxhrmiddleware.py app_name is the name of the app where you want to use this middleware.